# Swing - Group Layout

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I am coding a GUI in Swing and I am using `Grouplayout`

Here is my code:

```
    GroupLayout tLayout = new GroupLayout(card3ContentPane);
    card3ContentPane.setLayout(tLayout);
    tLayout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
    tLayout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    tLayout.setHorizontalGroup(tLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                    .addComponent(label))
                    .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                            .addComponent(lname)
                            .addComponent(lpreis)
                            .addComponent(lalter)
                            .addComponent(lkategorie))
                            .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                                    .addComponent(textname)
                                    .addComponent(textpreis)
                                    .addComponent(textalter)
                                    .addComponent(combo)
                                    .addComponent(bsuchen))
                                    .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                                            .addComponent(table))
            );

    tLayout.setVerticalGroup(tLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(label)
            .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                    .addComponent(lname)
                    .addComponent(textname))
                    .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                            .addComponent(lpreis)
                            .addComponent(textpreis))
                            .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                                    .addComponent(lalter)
                                    .addComponent(textalter))
                                    .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                                            .addComponent(lkategorie)
                                            .addComponent(combo))
                                            .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                                                    .addComponent(bsuchen))
                                                    .addGroup(tLayout.createParallelGroup()
                                                            .addComponent(table)));


    log.info("Leave showWarenSuchen");


}
```

Here is a screen-shot of how it looks like right now:  http://www.bilder-space.de/bilder/e7423f-1332615779.jpg

How can I place them in a vertical order, not so chaotic like right now?

[image]

Comment: A little more information and a picture of the desired output might help. Also, why not use more user-friendly layouts such as can be achieved by nesting JPanels each using a much simpler layout manager than GroupLayout?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  When you do 1) It helps to use attribute (& method) names in English 2) Edit it directly into the thread & use code formatting.

Comment: GroupLayout was meant for tools to generate and isn't really the best layout for writing manually.

Comment: GroupLayout is awesome, and I hand-code it regularly but the chaining syntax if over used leads to some truly unreadable code. The chaining syntax isn't compulsory, I use it sparingly.

Comment: I noticed that you don't use sequentian groups in vertical layout. It means that you don't understand very well how grouplayout works. Please take a look at Sun's docs. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html